# what happens to cache and DRAM when executing "a=5"?

Tags: caching, memory

If a process writes a immediate operand to an address

```
int a;
a = 5;
```

what happens to L1-Data cache and DRAM?
DRAM fills "5" first or L1-Data Cache fills "5" first?

Comment: To nitpick, perhaps nothing? That really depends on how `a` is used and how the compiler optimizes the code.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler assigns some memory address to variable a. In the second statement, when a = 5 is executed, if the system is a multi-processor system, a request will be sent downstream to invalidate all lines and give the processor executing the code this particular cache address in a unique cache coherency state. The value of 5 is then written to the L1 cache (assuming the compiler wants to keep the cacheline address in the cache and does not deem that this should be written back to memory/DRAM).

Comment: Thanks! You means the value "5" was written to L1 cache, and the DRAM do not have the value in this time, right?